# grabbing a table row's index using querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I can pull out the first occurance of a `table row` within `#myTable`, but how can I determine its `rowIndex` within `#myTable`?

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/fmj6np6m/1/

`html` ..

```
<table id="otherTable"></table>
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

`js` ..

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable"),
        row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length),
        cell0 = row.insertCell(0),
        cell1 = row.insertCell(1),
        cell2 = row.insertCell(2);

    var dirText = document.createTextNode('1');
    cell0.appendChild(dirText);

    var filenameText = document.createTextNode('1');
    cell1.appendChild(filenameText);
}

for (var l = 0; l < document.getElementById('myTable').rows.length; l++) {
    document.getElementById('myTable').rows[l].className = 'none';
}

document.getElementById('myTable').rows[2].className = 'showRow';
alert(document.querySelector('#myTable tr.showRow'));
```

`css` ..

```
.none {
    display: none;
}
.showRow {
    display: table-row;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: why the down votes without commenting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the row-index of the first row that matches a selector, you can use

```js
table.rows.length-1 - document.querySelectorAll(selector + ' ~ tr').length;
```

More in general, if you want to get the row-index of an arbitrary row,

```js
[].indexOf.call(table.rows, row);
```

In your case,

```js
table.rows.length-1
  - document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr.showRow ~ tr').length;
[].indexOf.call(table.rows, document.querySelector('#myTable tr.showRow'));
```